# maximal intersection between n sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have x sets with y elements(unsorted integers) in each of them. I want to find maximal size of intersection between pair of this sets.

*For example:*

> *5 sets, size = 3
>
> set 1 : 1 **2 3**
>
> set 2 : 4 **2 3**
>
> set 3 : 5 6 7
>
> set 4 : 5 8 9
>
> set 5 : 5 10 11

maximal intersection have set 1 with set 2 and it's size is 2;
the answer is 2.

So, I can do it in O(x^2 * y) using `HashSets`, by just looking out all pairs and calculating their intersection size. But I want to do it faster. I think there are specific algorithm or data structure that can help. Can you give me some idea?

**UPDATE** : x and y is about 10^3, elements are int. And there are no equals sets.

Comment: Would set 1 and 2 intersect also if `set 1: 1 3 2` and `set 2: 4 2 3`, i.e. the order of elements within a set do not matter?

Comment: yes the order doesnt matter

Comment: Is there any limit on the values of the elements? How about the number of sets -  do you have a limit on this?

Comment: Elements are int, x and y are about 1000. If you have idea how to do it with small elements, it will be useful too.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you had 3 sets, with an intersection of size 2 between set 1 and set 2, and an intersection of size 5 between set 2 and set 3, the answer you're looking for is 5, not 7, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for maximal intersection, not for sum of all intersections.

Answer (score 4):

One optimisation that I can think of is remembering intersection size between the first set and the rest of them and then use the data to cut some cases.

How you can use it:

If you have sets `A`, `B`, `C` of length `n` and

```
intersection(A,B) = p
intersection(A,C) = q
```

then

```
intersection(B,C) <= n - abs(p - q)
```

For sets in your case:

```
S0 = { 1 2 3 }
S1 = { 4 2 3 }
S2 = { 5 6 7 }
```

you compute `intersection(S0,S1) = 2` and remember the result:

```
[ i(0,1)=2 ]
```

then `intersection(S0,S2) = 0`, so

```
[ i(0,1)=2; i(0,2)=0 ]
```

And when you compute `intersection(S1,S2)` after comparing first elements

```
(S1[0]=4 != S2[0]=5)
```

you can say that `intersection(S1,S2) <= 2` that is the best result that you have so far.

What can be further improvement is to remember more exact results of intersections but still not computing all of them.

I'm not sure if that's the best option. Maybe there exists totally different approach to this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some psuedocode:

```
function max_intersection(vector<vector<int>> sets):
    hashmap<int, vector<set_id>> val_map;
    foreach set_id:set in sets:
        foreach val in set:
            val_map[val].push_back(set_id);
    max_count = 0
    vector<int> counts = vector<int>(size = sets.size() * sets.size(), init_value = 0);
    foreach val:set_ids in val_map:
        foreach id_1:set_id_1 in set_ids:
            foreach id_2:set_id_2 in set_ids where id_2 > id_1:
                count = ++counts[set_id_1 * sets.size() + set_id_2];
                if (count > max_count):
                    max_count = count;
    return max_count;
```

So if `X` is the number of sets and `Y` is the number of elements in each set:

1. Inserting into `val_map` is `O(X*Y)`
2. Creating `counts` and initializing each element to zero is `O(X^2)`
3. If there are no intersections (each value occurs exactly once), the last loop runs in time `O(X*Y)`. However, at the other extreme, if there is a large number of intersections (all sets are equivalent), then the last loop runs in `O(X^2*Y)`.

So depending on the amount of intersections, the time complexity is somewhere between `O(X*Y + X^2)` and `O(X^2*Y)`.

Comment: The complexity of  algorithm is O(k^2 *y). k is average number of the sets containing a concrete number.

Answer (score 2):

I can not think of a solution that will improve `O(x*x*y)`, but I can suggest a way to avoid hashing and instead of **expected complexity** `O(x*x*y)` to have complexity `O(x*x*y)` at the cost of 10^6 additional memory. Looking at the constraints you've provided you will have no more than 10^6 different numbers. So my idea is the following - sort all the numbers and then unique them(remove duplicates). Assign unique number from 1 to 10^6(or the number of unique numbers) to each of the numbers(using their order in the sorted and uniqued array). After that instead of hashmap on for each pair, use a bit set of size 10^6. This way you will have a certain complexity of `O(x*x*y)`(as the precomputation I propose is of complexity `O(x * y *(log(x) + log (y))`).

Comment: Since you already sort+unique all numbers, you can also discard all numbers that appear just once -- since they cannot be in two different sets!  Won't change the complexity, but very cheap and may reduce the constant factor a lot (depending on the input distribution).

Comment: Yes I considered that but my proposal is focused on worst case rather than the average case

Comment: Complexity of your solution is O(x^2), but in fact it's O(x^2*10^6), isn't it?

Comment: @rusted no it is not.  It is O(x^2*y + 10^6) if implemented properly.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev But why? you have about x^2 pairs, each of them you "compare" using bitset with size 10^6. So x^2 pairs, 10^6 - each comparison => total is 10^6 * x^2
May be i didnt get your idea?

Comment: You iterate over all numbers in first set setting bits to one - complexity O(y) then you iterate over all numbers of the other set checking if the corresponding element is set to 1. Another O(y). Last iterate once more over the first set to set elements back to 0. Overall O(y)